# interest configuration on fixed amount

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

find total_charge from interest configuration using sql or plsql

```
START_FROM     END_TO   PER_UNIT    CHAR_PU   MIN_CHAR   MAX_CHAR INSTRUCTION                                       
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------------
         0       9999       1000          3         10          0 compare min                                       
     10000      29999       1000        2.5          3          0 add min                                        
     30000      99999       1000          2          0          0 compare                                           
    100000     999999       1000        1.5          0        300 compare max
```

steps:

1. get amount between start_from and End_to from the user. example.  0-9999 amount=5000
2. calculate charge through per_unit with validation of instruction.For example. amount=5000 charge=3 per=1000 total_charge= 15. but when amount=2000 then total_charge=6 in that case we need to validate instruction and it will compare to min_Charge=10 and the total_charge=10.
3. In 10000-29999 validation to Add min=total_charge+3
4. In 100000-999999 validation to Max_charge if it applies
5. amount get through '&' and total_charges shows in column

Comment: This is asking for a program, not asking a question. You need to at least attempt to solve this yourself, and then ask a specific question if there's something you can't figure out.
Out of interest though, where does 5000 come from in your example?

Comment: Ask a proper and clear question instead of this mess and make sure you supply any metadata, sample data and expected output needed to make it possible to help you.

Comment: it's static value for choose between amount of from and to

Comment: expected output would be total_Charge=10 for 1.row where amount between 0-9999

Comment: Attempt your own homework and post if you are having any difficulties while solving it. Pose your current attempt and what output you are getting right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calcu(amount NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER is charge NUMBER;
BEGIN SELECT ((amount/per_unit)*char_pu) into charge  from a where amount between start_from and end_to; if (charge<10) then charge:=10; elsif(amount between 10000 and 29999) then charge:=charge+3; elsif(charge>300) then charge:=300;
end if; RETURN charge; END calcu; select calcu(&amount) as charge from dual;`